# Finding $YOUR_DOCKER_HOST ip on mac

Tags: apache-spark, docker, pyspark

I have launched a container(one of the publicly available images from docker hub) to run my spark program. To open the spark Web UI, I need to go to http://:8080. Can anyone tell me how can I open this webUI?

Comment: Can you write a command that you used? 99% you need to bind guest port to host port

Comment: What is the output of command `docker ps`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you ran the container and mapped ports directly...

```
http://localhost:8080
```